# How to use FilteredRelation with OuterRef?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-orm

I'm trying to use Django ORM to generate a queryset and I can't find how to use an `OuterRef` in the joining condition with a `FilteredRelation`.

**What I have in Django**

*Main queryset*

```py
queryset = LineOutlier.objects.filter(report=self.kwargs['report_pk'], report__apn__customer__cen_id=self.kwargs['customer_cen_id']) \
                    .select_related('category__traffic') \
                    .select_related('category__frequency') \
                    .select_related('category__stability') \
                    .prefetch_related('category__traffic__labels') \
                    .prefetch_related('category__frequency__labels') \
                    .prefetch_related('category__stability__labels') \
                    .annotate(history=subquery)
```

*The subquery*

```py
subquery = ArraySubquery(
            LineOutlierReport.objects
            .filter((Q(lineoutlier__imsi=OuterRef('imsi')) | Q(lineoutlier__isnull=True)) & Q(id__in=last_5_reports_ids))
             .values(json=JSONObject(
                            severity='lineoutlier__severity',
                            report_id='id',
                            report_start_date='start_date',
                            report_end_date='end_date'
                            )
                    )
        )
```

The request can be executed, but the SQL generated is not exactly what I want :

**SQL Generated**

```sql
SELECT "mlformalima_lineoutlier"."id",
       "mlformalima_lineoutlier"."imsi",
       ARRAY(
        SELECT JSONB_BUILD_OBJECT('severity', V1."severity", 'report_id', V0."id", 'report_start_date', V0."start_date", 'report_end_date', V0."end_date") AS "json"
          FROM "mlformalima_lineoutlierreport" V0
          LEFT OUTER JOIN "mlformalima_lineoutlier" V1
            ON (V0."id" = V1."report_id")
         WHERE ((V1."imsi" = ("mlformalima_lineoutlier"."imsi") OR V1."id" IS NULL) AND V0."id" IN (SELECT DISTINCT ON (U0."id") U0."id" FROM "mlformalima_lineoutlierreport" U0 WHERE U0."apn_id" = 2 ORDER BY U0."id" ASC, U0."end_date" DESC LIMIT 5))
       ) AS "history",
  FROM "mlformalima_lineoutlier"
```

The problem here is that the `OuterRef` condition `(V1."imsi" = ("mlformalima_lineoutlier"."imsi"))` is done on the `WHERE` statement, and I want it to be on the `JOIN` statement

**What I want in SQL**

```sql
SELECT "mlformalima_lineoutlier"."id",
       "mlformalima_lineoutlier"."imsi",
       ARRAY(
        SELECT JSONB_BUILD_OBJECT('severity', V1."severity", 'report_id', V0."id", 'report_start_date', V0."start_date", 'report_end_date', V0."end_date") AS "json"
          FROM "mlformalima_lineoutlierreport" V0
          LEFT OUTER JOIN "mlformalima_lineoutlier" V1
            ON (V0."id" = V1."report_id" AND ((V1."id" IS NULL) OR V1."imsi" = ("mlformalima_lineoutlier"."imsi")))
         WHERE V0."id" IN (SELECT DISTINCT ON (U0."id") U0."id" FROM "mlformalima_lineoutlierreport" U0 WHERE U0."apn_id" = 2 ORDER BY U0."id" ASC, U0."end_date" DESC LIMIT 5))
       ) AS "history",
  FROM "mlformalima_lineoutlier"
```

**What I tried in Django**

I tried to use the `FilteredRelation` to change the JOIN condition, but I can't seem to use it in combination with an `OuterRef`

```py
subquery = ArraySubquery(
            LineOutlierReport.objects
            .annotate(filtered_relation=FilteredRelation('lineoutlier', condition=Q(lineoutlier__imsi=OuterRef('imsi')) | Q(lineoutlier__isnull=True)))
            .filter(Q(id__in=last_5_reports_ids))
            .values(json=JSONObject(
                            severity='filtered_relation__severity',
                            report_id='id',
                            report_start_date='start_date',
                            report_end_date='end_date'
                            )
                    )
        )
```

I can't execute this query because of the following error

`ValueError: This queryset contains a reference to an outer query and may only be used in a subquery.`

How can I modify my query to make it work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like [this Django bug](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/33766). As a workaround you can annotate another column and reference it in the `FilteredRelation`, like so :

```py
subquery = ArraySubquery(
        LineOutlierReport.objects
        .annotate(
            outer_imsi=OuterRef('imsi'),
            filtered_relation=FilteredRelation('lineoutlier', condition=Q(lineoutlier__imsi=F('outer_imsi')) | Q(lineoutlier__isnull=True)))
        .filter(Q(id__in=last_5_reports_ids))
        .values(json=JSONObject(
                        severity='filtered_relation__severity',
                        report_id='id',
                        report_start_date='start_date',
                        report_end_date='end_date'
                        )
                )
    )
```

That way you avoid `OuterRef` being processed inside `FilteredRelation`.